# How to trigger a hudson job by another job which is in a different hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I have job A in Hudson A and Job B in Hudson B. I want to trigger job A by Job B.

Comment: any one who knows the answer plz revert soon , its really urgent.....plz help

Comment: A lack of planning or reading on your part doesn't constitute an emergency on ours.

Comment: Ever thought about a hudson slave? Or do you really need two independent Hudson server?

Answer (score 6):

In your job B configuration, check the **Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)** checkbox and provide a token.

The help text there shows you the URL you can call to trigger a build from remote scripts (e.g. from a shell script in Hudson job A).

However, that would trigger job B no matter what the result of job A is.
Morechilli's answer is probably the best solution.

Comment: When one step of a job fails, Hudson does not execute the following steps. So when your call of the remote job is the last step it will only execute if the previous step was successful.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used Hudson but I would guess your simplest approach would be to use the URL trigger:

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/URL+Change+Trigger

I think there is a latest build url that could be used for this.

Comment: I think the last successful URL http://SERVER:PORT/job/JOBNAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/ should work with the URL change trigger, if you want to trigger job B only if job A is successful. If job B should always be triggered, try the last build URLhttp://SERVER:PORT/job/JOBNAME/lastBuild/

Answer (score 4):

In the latest versions of Hudson, the lastSuccessfultBuild/ HTML page will contain the elapased time since it was built, which will be different for each call. This causes the URL Change Trigger to spin.

One fix is to use the xml, json, or python APIs to request only a subset of the information. Using the 'tree' request parameter, the following URL will return an XML document containing only the build number of the last successful build.

http://SERVER:PORT/job/JOBNAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?tree=number

Using this URL restored the behavior I expected from the URL Change Trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the easiest way to do this is to watch the build timestamp:
`PROJECT_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildTimestamp`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **wget** to trigger the build:

```
wget --post-data 'it-just-need-to-be-a-POST-request' 
--auth-no-challenge --http-user=myuser --http-password=mypassword
http://jenkins.xx.xx/xxx/job/A/build?delay=0sec
```

There's other ways how you can trigger a build, see the REST and other APIs of jenkins.
But this works great on unix.